# SQL Query to delete two rows where end of string value is identical

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table which has 4 columns (`id`,`name`,`value`,`group`) and ~150,000 rows.

I need to delete all occurrences of any set of two rows where the `name` column value ends in the same string (a uuid) AND the `value` column value of the second row is before a specified date.

A `name` column value always starts with one of two strings: `st1_` always has json data in the `value` columns, `st2_` always has a unix timestamp in the `value` column.

Here's a sample set (`group` column is removed because it doesn't matter):

```
╔════╦═══════════╦════════════╗
║ id ║   name    ║   value    ║
╠════╬═══════════╬════════════╣
║ 1  ║ st1_uuid1 ║ {json}     ║
║ 2  ║ st2_uuid1 ║ 1448880401 ║
║ 3  ║ st1_uuid2 ║ {json}     ║          
║ 4  ║ st2_uuid2 ║ 1448880414 ║
║ 5  ║ st1_uuid3 ║ {json}     ║    
║ 6  ║ st2_uuid3 ║ 1448880468 ║
╚════╩═══════════╩════════════╝
```

In this example, how could I write a query to delete rows 1-4 based on their unix timestamp?

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9773e/2)

Comment: So is your `value` column actually `VARCHAR`, sometimes holding JSON and other times holding a text version of a timestamp?

Comment: You should seriously consider normalizing your table structure and not storing JSON and timestamps in the same column.

Comment: The `value` column always contains either JSON or a timestamp, but it's predictable based on the string prefixed to the UUID in the `name` column—`st1_` always has JSON in `value, `st2_` always has a timestamp.

Comment: As for normalisation: it's not an option as it's a third party application that adds this data to the database. The table contains other data and they were just shoehorning the data into that table using it's structure. `st1_` and `st2_` are actually the application's name so you can search the database for its content using `LIKE %st2\_%`.

Comment: I'm trying your answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query should work assuming that the `uuid` values which occur more than once should all be considered together when determining duplicates.

```
DELETE FROM yourTable
WHERE RIGHT(name, 32) IN (SELECT * 
             FROM (SELECT RIGHT(name, 32) FROM yourTable 
                   GROUP BY RIGHT(name, 32)
                   HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 AND
                   MIN(CASE WHEN value REGEXP '[0-9]+' THEN CAST(value AS UNSIGNED) ELSE ~0 END) < someValue
                  ) AS t
            )
```

Here is SQL Fiddle demonstrating that the `GROUP BY` query correctly identifies `uuids` from the records which should be deleted for a given timestamp `someValue`:

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d42c01/12)

Comment: That's a very useful edit. It's pretty close to working, I think. The one problem is I'm getting `FUNCTION yourTable.MIN does not exist. Check the 'Function Name Parsing and Resolution' section in the Reference Manual`. So it looks like MySQL 5.5.47 doesn't have `MIN()`? I'll look that up.

Comment: Are you missing a parenthesis somewhere?  Did you copy over the `AND` operator in the `HAVING` clause?  I am asking this because I didn't see these errors in the Fiddle.

Comment: A space got added between `MIN` and `(`. I just responded too quickly. I've updated your SQLFiddle, see my edit on the post for that.

Comment: Updated. Thanks. Sorry, It's my first time using their tool. Didn't realise you need to do 'Build Schema' or it wouldn't add/save the query.

Answer (score 0):

This query creates a string like "st1_uuid1,st2_uuid1,st1_uuid3,st2_uuid3," with name of variables that need to be deleted and checks if the name of each record is in this string.

```
DELETE FROM Table1 WHERE 
INSTR((SELECT * FROM (
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( CONCAT('st1_uuid',SUBSTRING(name,9),',',name) SEPARATOR ', ') 
FROM Table1 WHERE value REGEXP '^[0-9]+$' AND value<1448880414) as t), name);
```

If it can be assumed that the variables st1_uuidX and st2_uuidX are going to have consecutive id numbers then if we know the id number of st2_uuidX then the id of the st1_uuidX should be one minus that of st2_uuidX.

```
FROM Table1 WHERE id IN 
(SELECT * FROM (SELECT id FROM Table1 WHERE value REGEXP '^[0-9]+$' AND value<1448880414) as t) 
OR id IN (SELECT * FROM (SELECT id-1 FROM Table1 WHERE value REGEXP '^[0-9]+$' AND value<1448880414) as r)
```

Both queries had been tested.